# Knockout - Accessing length of array "bound to" from inside template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have different objects/view models that holds similar data but in different properties.

Think of it as an object holding 2 lists;

- List of "Something"
- List of "Groups"

where a group also contains a list of "Something", similar to this

```
function group(d) {
  this.name = ko.observable(d.name)
  this.anotherList = ko.observableArray(d.data);
}
function vm() {
  this.list1 = ko.observableArray([1,2,3,4]);
  this.list2 = ko.observableArray([new group({name:'a', data:[9,8,7,6]})]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

One requirement is that I must output the posisiton and length of the bound arrays. Currently it is done by repeating the code for each list element, like this:

```
<div>
    <h3>Specific for each list</h3>
    <hr />
    <ul data-bind="foreach: list1">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: $data">Data</span> - Is number
            <span data-bind="text: $index()+1">x</span> of
            <span data-bind="text: $parent.list1().length">n</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <br />
    <h4>Inside group</h4>
    <!-- ko foreach: list2 -->
    <ol data-bind="foreach: anotherList">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: $data">Data</span> - Is number
            <span data-bind="text: $index()+1">x</span> of
            <span data-bind="text: $parent.anotherList().length">n</span>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

What I would like to achieve is to use the same template to render the "bottom" content - the lists.

```
<div>
    <h3>Using a template</h3>
    <hr />
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'listElement', foreach: list1 }"></ul>
    <br />
    <h4>Inside group</h4>
    <span data-bind="foreach: list2">
        <ol data-bind="template: { name: 'listElement', foreach: anotherList }"></ol>
    </span>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="listElement">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data">Data</span> - Is number
        <span data-bind="text: $index()+1">x</span> of <strong><span>n???</span></strong>
    </li>
</script>
```

I have looked at the binding context, etc, but can't seem to find a nice way of doing it. Maybe I need to create a custom binding that exposes the length along with the data? (hope not)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skattefuten/e6s2X/

Comment: One way to do without a custom binding to move the foreach logic inside the template: http://jsfiddle.net/aNY7x/

Comment: Just noticed I didn't include the correct fiddle, but an earlier version without the grouping, Sorry for that. I have updated the fiddle. I might be able to solve it your way.... (checking)

Comment: So simple and it works. Thanks a lot. Please provide it as an answer:-)   Fiddle with your solution integrated: http://jsfiddle.net/skattefuten/e6s2X/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it without using a custom binding is to move the "foreach logic" inside your template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="listElement">
    <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: $data">Data</span> - Is number 
            <span data-bind="text: $index()+1">x</span> of <strong>
            <span data-bind="text: $parent.length"></span></strong>
        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

Then you can use the `$parent.length` to access the length of your arrays.

And in your templates you need to pass in your arrays with the `data` property:

```
<div>
    <h3>Using a template</h3>
    <hr />
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'listElement', data: list1 }"></ul>
    <br />
    <h4>Inside group</h4>
    <span data-bind="foreach: list2">
        <ol data-bind="template: { name: 'listElement', data: anotherList }">
        </ol>
    </span>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skattefuten/e6s2X/4/).